# Can you kill a human with a Death Note in less than forty seconds?

Tags: death-note

If I were write in the Death Note:

> Bob Bold Heart attack NOW.

Would that work?

Answer (score 13):

According to the first rule in [How To Use III](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note)

> If the time of death is written within 40 seconds after writing the cause of death as a heart attack, the time of death can be manipulated, and the **time can go into effect within 40 seconds after writing the name**.

So the time of death (e.g. "NOW") won't go into effect for 40 seconds.

Comment: so that means when i would write: epileptic attack NOW. that would work?

Comment: My guess is it doesn't matter what the cause of death is. The part of the rule just states that if you write a time of death, and the cause is heart attack, you can manipulate the time of death. I guess it depends on your you read the "and". It's not, "then the time can go into effect", it's (after you do all of that first part,) "also the time can go into effect"

Comment: so you cant kill a person with a death note in less than 40 seconds?

Comment: No, that's exactly what the rule says. 40 seconds have to pass since the killing note is written down.

Comment: That doesn't look like it's saying it won't take effect until 40 seconds are up; it looks like it's saying it **can** go into effect within 40 seconds.

Comment: @user2357112 For one, I'm not entirely sure (in the spirit of the show) "NOW" constitutes an actual time of death. If "NOW" happens within some point between the writing and 40 seconds, it's not really "NOW" (as in the time of the writing) anymore, since it had already passed. The whole 40 second buffer is to give you the ability *to go back and change some of the things you've written*. If the "now" were to take effect, the buffer becomes pointless.